# Why doesn't my site respond to the size of my browser window?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, viewport, meta

I have created a page with media queries in my CSS so that it should respond to the viewport of the device.

When I use the Firefox web dev tool for responsive design I can see how my site reacts. But when I resize my browser I cannot.

http://champlain.torqueweb.com/html/Responsive1.html

Should I use a different value for my meta?

Comment: Consider reading this help topic on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on Stack Overflow. After reading, edit your question. There's potential for this to be on-topic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

max-device-width should be:

max-width

Works, I tested it

Comment: Device width looks at the device, so if you resize the Browser, it won't matter

Comment: That did it! Thanks! This is my first responsive site. The meta must match the media query. Good to know! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You are using fixed width in your style sheet.

F.i.

```
nav {
width:1024px; <<<< prevents responsiveness as the width will be fixed
height:40px;  
font-family: Arial;
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
list-style: none;
background-color: #000033;
}
```

These fixed widths are not reset in your media queries (i.e. @media ...).

Either make the modifications in the media queries or better still use % or em messurements where it is not absolutely required to have fixed width or height.

F.i.

```
nav {
width:100%; <<<< will resize to the max available width
height:40px;  
font-family: Arial;
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
list-style: none;
background-color: #000033;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Point 1 is you are centering the page up, I think we shouldn't center the page up(I mean the whole body thing or even the container) for a responsive page design...

Like if you do not actually define the width property, the browser will assume at take it as auto, so the page will spread through out the browser window.

Maybe that should be helpfull(don't judge me, I am not very experienced :O)